# iOS swift search bar

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am a beginner in Swift.

I am currently implementing a search bar that can searched by multiple fields.

From my knowledge, I know that we need an array for iOS swift search bar.

Below are the codes that I am having currently. I have no idea why my search has no result and I have already confirmed that I have data in my array.

updateSearchResultsForSearchController.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filtered.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    for i in 0...arrProcessName.count{

        if(arrProcessName[safe: i] != nil && arrRequestedBy[safe: i] != nil && arrCreationTime[safe: i] != nil && arrStatus[safe: i] != nil)
        {
        allItems += [(process:arrProcessName[i], requestor:arrRequestedBy[i], creation:arrCreationTime[i], status:arrStatus[i])]
        }
    }
    tableView?.reloadData()
}
```

searchBar.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("testing", searchText)
    filtered = allItems.filter({ data in
        let tmp: NSString = data.process
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    tableView?.reloadData()
}
```

tableView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.searchCtrler.active {
        return filtered.count
    } else {
        return arrRequestedBy.count
    }
}
```

tableView with indexPath.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    removeProgressBar()
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HistoryCustomCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

    if self.searchCtrler.active {
        cell.lbl_request_name.text = filtered[indexPath.row].process
        cell.lbl_requested_by.text = filtered[indexPath.row].requestor
        cell.lbl_creation_time.text = filtered[indexPath.row].creation
        cell.lbl_status.text = filtered[indexPath.row].status
    } else {
        cell.lbl_request_name.text = arrProcessName[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_requested_by.text = "Requested by: " + arrRequestedBy[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_creation_time.text = arrCreationTime[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl_status.text = arrStatus[indexPath.row]

        switch arrStatus[indexPath.row] {
            case "Completed", "Approved":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_approved")
            case "Running", "Processing", "Pending":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_pending")
            case "Denied", "Rejected":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_reject")
            case "Error":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_terminated")
            case "Retracted":
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "ic_retracted")
            default:
                cell.img_status.image = UIImage(named: "")
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

My situation now is that I don't get any result when I am using my search bar. Please help. I really can't find much information about having multiple search field on the Internet. Your answers will be appreciated.

Comment: check if filtered list  having value in method updateSearchResultsForSearchController.If  searchbar active you taking filtered array to  populate

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose The filtered list is empty. the problem i am facing now is that. i don't know how to call the searchBar function from updateSearchResultsForSearchController function

Comment: seems like you are appending to "allItems"that is never used. filtered = allItems.

Comment: yes just tried filtered = allItems. there are data now. but my filter doesn't work. As I am using tuple and I have no idea why I can't use predicate for tuple