# Cannot convert value of type ... to type

Tags: swift, nsarray

I am facing error to put my tuple as a NSArray.

My code is shown as below.

```
var Name: [String] = []
var Requested: [String] = []
var Time: [String] = []
var Status: [String] = []

var filtered: [(process:String, requestor:String, creation:String, status:String)] = []
var allItems: [(process:String, requestor:String, creation:String, status:String)] = []

for i in 0...Name.count{
        if(Name[safe: i] != nil && Requested[safe: i] != nil && Time[safe: i] != nil && Status[safe: i] != nil)
        {
        allItems += [(process:Name[i], requestor:Requested[i], creation:Time[i], status:Status[i])]
        }
    }
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (allItems as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

I wanted to use filteredArrayUsingPredicate in this case. But I am facing

> Cannot convert value of type '[(process: String, requestor: String, creation: String, status: String)]' to type 'NSArray' in coercion

Can anyone tell me why am I facing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why am I facing this error?

Certainly. NSArray is an Objective-C class. The only objects that can be elements of an NSArray are Objective-C objects. There is no such thing as a tuple in Objective-C; a tuple is a *Swift* object. An array of Swift objects cannot be turned into an NSArray.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anything I can use instead of NSArray?

Comment: Not if you insist on calling `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`. It is an NSArray method.

Comment: However, you did not ask for alternatives or other ways to do what you are trying to do. You didn't even explain what you are trying to do. Your question was why you are getting this compiler error, and I've told you, correctly, why that is.

Comment: help me with this link pls @matt. Tq for your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606738/ios-swift-search-bar?noredirect=1#comment68450858_40606738